# Remove last character in selected column?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

Query:

```
select * from aa;
```

Output:

```
ID  FirstName   LastName    City
-----------------------------------
29  Abcrdrr     hai         chennai
67  adf         adsd        adsf
1   John        vinoth      CITY
```

I want to display the `lastname` column without last character. I am using following queries:

```
Declare @name as varchar(100);

select @name = city from aa
Select @name, left(@name, len(@name)-1) as AfterRemoveLastCharacter
```

But output will come first row only

Answer (score 8):

"The first shall be last, and the last shall be first"

```
REVERSE(STUFF ( REVERSE(lastname), 1, 1, ''))
```

Comment: Voting up for the comment alone.

Answer (score 1):

Quick and dirty, probably good enough:

```
SELECT
    ID
    ,FirstName
    ,CASE WHEN LEN(LEN(RTRIM(LastName)))>1 THEN LEFT(LastName,LEN(RTRIM(LastName))-1) ELSE '' END AS LastName
    ,City 
FROM [table]
```

Comment: Suppose i run this query  Last Name Column Display Empty values

Comment: Sorry  This query working good. To Change (>1) into ( >=1)

Comment: @Vinoth_S, doing LEFT(field,0) throws an exception - which is 1-1 - so you'll want to consider that.

Answer (score 1):

I found this can make more sense:

```
select 
    txt, 
    left(txt, abs(len(txt + ',') - 2))
from 
    t;
```

[`[SQL Fiddle Demo]`](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9eecb7db59d16c80417c72d1e1f4fbf1/3086)

> Provides these without any error:
>    * Last character removed for a normal string.
>    * Last character removed for a space ended string.
>    * Last character removed for a single space character string.
>    * Empty-string results in empty-string.
>    * null results in null
>   [`[SQL Fiddle Demo]`](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9eecb7db59d16c80417c72d1e1f4fbf1/3087)